# KOMA scrreprt + esint + minipage + textsc incompatibility

Tags: fonts, koma-script, scrreprt

Interestingly this error appears only when all of the components are present. It initially appeared when I tried to use `microtype`, but I managed to reproduce it without `microtype`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{esint}

%\usepackage[german,ngerman]{babel}     %Language
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}           %Encoding
%\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}                %Encoding
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{0.35\textwidth}
        \textsc{Some random string}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
Font U/esint/m/n/10.95=esint10 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \end{minipage}
Font U/esint/m/n/8=esint10 at 8.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \end{minipage}
Font U/esint/m/n/6=esint10 at 6.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \end{minipage}
```

pdflatex --version

```
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6499 (1.40.18) (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2016 Han The Thanh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.56.1; using libcurl/7.56.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2; using expat_2.2.0
compiled with jpeg version 9.2
compiled with liblzma version 50020032; using 50020032
compiled with libpng version 1.6.34; using 1.6.34
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.5.3; using LibreSSL 2.5.3
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 2.6416; using 2.6416
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 3.6505; using 3.6531
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 1.6300; using 1.6300
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 1.6488; using 1.6488
compiled with poppler version 0.60.1
compiled with uriparser version 0.8.4
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

Additional version information:

```
esint version 1.2b (packaged 20.07.2019)
esint-type1 installed (packaged 29.07.2019)
koma-script 3.26b (packaged 04.02.2019)
```

Comment: Woudn't the error come from the postscript fonts databases (`dvips.map`, `pdftex.map` &c.)not being updated? Try `updmap --admin --verbose` from the command line.

Comment: miktex has only the metafont sources and tries to create the tfm on the fly and this fails. It fails in texlive too if I remove the existing tfm, so I think the mf-files are faulty.

Comment: the mf-file is empty. No wonder that nothing can be created.

Comment: That is clearly a esint bug. I did sent the author a mail.

Comment: The author will upload a new version to ctan. The problem should be resolved soon.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sounds great. I'm not sure what should be documented as an answer to this question, but someone is ought to come up with something meaningful.