# PDF will not print, font error

Tags: errors, compiling

My pdf does not compile and I receive the following error in my log file:

> "!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file esint10): Font esint10 at 600 not found"

I have added `\usepackage{lmodern}` as I have read that that is a common fix for this problem (though it does not sus out the root of the issue), but this is not working for me and I am receiving the same error.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! First this means pdflatex doesn't find the  type 1 font`esint`, since it tries to find bitmap fonts. Is your distribution MiKTeX, per chance?

Comment: If you are using MiKTeX, please see the comments to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/505144/16550

Comment: @Bernard Yes, I am using MiKTeX.

Comment: @Mensch, I did not find that particularly helpful. Is this just a bug that will be fixed soon (hopefully)?

Comment: Yes, seems to be a bug with font `esint` and MiKTeX. See the last comment in the linked question ...

Comment: Open MiKTeX console, and in the `Tasks` menu, click on `Refresh font map files`, both as administrator and as user. When you install a font with MiKTeX Package manager, from time to time, refreshing font map files is omitted. It's not really a bug, just an oversight.

Comment: @Bernard there is currently a real bug in the esint package which shows on miktex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what will be the fix for me once the bug has been fixed?

Comment: when the esint package is updated it should be usable again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer so has this been fixed yet? I looked at the other question and it was not clear from the comments